# Can't find the right MySQL query, please take a look

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried to find a solution for a while, but seems that my current knowledge is not enough to solve this case. Please help.

I have the following MySQL table:

```
_____________________________________
| client_id | project_id | products |
| 1         | 1          | 2        |
| 4         | 2          | 7        |
| 1         | 2          | 3        |
| 1         | 2          | 8        |
|___________|____________|__________|
```

I want to find the number of projects based on a specific project_id, but I need the result to consider the client_id, for example: project_id=2 (that appears 3 times) should be counted only twice, because it appears twice for the same client (client_id=1).

Please help me with the MySQL query to get this type of result.

I hope my explanation is clear enough... Thank you so much.

Comment: Use `GROUP BY client_id`

Comment: What is the PK, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE client_id = 1 AND project_id = 2

Answer (score 0):

You should study GROUP BY documentation and then post things youve tried and didnt work. We should see some effort before writing you whole solution

Comment: Ok maybe i was wrong This should do it select count(distinct client_id) as count from t1 as t where t.project_id=2